# Powershell - how to get Location of job with job result in one table?

Tags: powershell, powershell-jobs

I want to get serial numbers of remote PC's with the name of PC, in one table.
$PCNameArray is array of remote PC I want to get serial numbers.

```
$complete = $false
$arrayJobs = @()

Foreach($a in $PCNameArray) {
    $arrayJobs += Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $a -Class Win32_BIOS -asjob
}

while (-not $complete) {
    $arrayJobsInProgress = $arrayJobs |
        Where-Object { $_.State -match ‘running’ }
    if (-not $arrayJobsInProgress) { “All Jobs Have Completed” ; $complete = $true }
}

$arrayJobs | Receive-Job
```

this code will give me only serial numbers. How can I add each PC names to this result?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The computer name *is* returned as a property of the returned WMI object, it's just not shown by default.  You can show it like this:

```
$arrayJobs = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $PCNameArray -Class Win32_BIOS -asjob

Wait-Job $arrayJobs

$arrayJobs |
    Receive-Job |
    Format-Table PsComputerName, SerialNumber -AutoSize
```

This gives output like this:

```
PSComputerName SerialNumber                    
-------------- ------------                    
Server1        0000-0000-2620-2195-4000-8654-21
Server2        0000-0013-3219-1963-9428-8113-87
Server3        0000-0004-9473-4695-9509-1141-89
```

`PsComputerName` is added to the WMI object by PowerShell, but the object itself has a `__Server` property that also contains the computer name.  You can see everything that is returned by replacing `Format-Table PsComputerName, SerialNumber -AutoSize` in the above example with `Format-List *`

Comment: Wow, thank you, that's what I want!
I didn't know that I can send $PCNameArray to Get-WMIObject directly, and I used this tip https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/hey-scripting-guy-how-can-i-receive-all-windows-powershell-jobs/ to waiting all jobs, instead of using Wait-Job.
Thank you!